# Extract tags from TMX (XML) content using PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am building a browser-based TMX (translation memories) editor. My content extraction script breaks when the source and/or target segment contains tags. A source/target string containing tags looks like this:

```
<tuv xml:lang="BG">
  <seg><bpt x="1" i="1" type="italic"/>Формантът -лар/-лар- (от тюрк. -lar) е слабо представен в българската словообразувателна система.<ept i="1"/></seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="EN-GB">
  <seg><bpt x="1" i="1" type="italic"/>The -lar/-lar- formant (from the Turkic -lar) is sparsely represented in the Bulgarian word-building system.<ept i="1"/></seg>
</tuv>
```

If there are no tags in the source/target segment, extraction is easy:

```
$sourceText = $TU['tuv'][0]['seg'];
$targetText = $TU['tuv'][1]['seg'];
```

But I am stuck for a solution when tags are present (in initial position). Particularly because these tags are treated as arrays.

I can't figure out how to proceed: I can check if the source/target string contains/is an array but not sure what to do next. Ultimately, I need to print the text together with the tags to let the user edit the text and move/delete the tags if necessary.

Here's my testing code:

```
$uploadedFile = "user_files/sample_tmx.tmx";

$xmlStr = file_get_contents($uploadedFile);
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
$arrXml = $util->objectsIntoArray($xmlObj);
$TUs = $arrXml['body']['tu'];

$pattern = '~<.*?>~';

foreach($TUs as $TU) {

    if(is_array($TU['tuv'][0]['seg'])) {

        var_dump($TU['tuv'][0]['seg']);

        $pattern = '~<.*?>~';
        $uncleanSource = $TU['tuv'][0]['seg'];
        $uncleanTarget = $TU['tuv'][1]['seg'];

        foreach($uncleanSource as $unclean) {
            //var_dump($unclean);
        }

        //$sourceText = preg_replace($pattern, "&lt;TAG&gt;", $uncleanSource);
        //$targetText = preg_replace($pattern, "&lt;TAG&gt;", $uncleanTarget);
    }
    else {
        $sourceText = $TU['tuv'][0]['seg'];
        $targetText = $TU['tuv'][1]['seg'];
    }

    echo "<p>".$sourceText." = ".$targetText."</p>";
}
```

And this is the sample_tmx.tmx file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd" >
<tmx version="1.4">
<header creationtool="TDC Analysis Package" creationtoolversion="org.gs4tr.tm3.tmx.Version" segtype="sentence" o-tmf="unknown" adminlang="EN-US" srclang="BG" datatype="unknown" creationdate="20221006T184234Z" >
</header>
<body>
<tu creationdate="20201101T133734Z" creationid="Cheeseus" changedate="20201103T151745Z" changeid="Cheeseus" usagecount="0">
    <prop type="nextMd5Checksum">e82d0ed6d711aa59310d1e8f4478537e</prop>
    <prop type="previousMd5Checksum">39b279e324e9f6cd27351287502eefcb</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="BG">
      <seg><bpt x="1" i="1" type="italic"/>Формантът -лар/-лар- (от тюрк. -lar) е слабо представен в българската словообразувателна система.<ept i="1"/></seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="EN-GB">
      <seg><bpt x="1" i="1" type="italic"/>The -lar/-lar- formant (from the Turkic -lar) is sparsely represented in the Bulgarian word-building system.<ept i="1"/></seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>
  <tu creationdate="20080812T111221Z" creationid="Cheeseus" changedate="20190825T065920Z" changeid="Cheeseus" usagecount="0">
    <tuv xml:lang="BG">
      <seg>ПАРТНЬОРИ</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="EN-GB">
      <seg>PARTNERS</seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>
</body>
</tmx>
```

Comment: Does changing it to `$TU['tuv'][0]['seg']->asXML()` help?

Comment: @NigelRen, No, it doesn't. It throws an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function asXML() on array`.

Comment: So did you try `$TU['tuv'][0]['seg'][0]->asXML()`

Comment: @NigelRen, I just did: I get the same error.

Comment: It looks like whatever `objectsIntoArray` is doing to the content, it's making the structure difficult to work out. If you miss out this step you can get the results as indicated above. (although you would have to rework your code as well)

Comment: @NigelRen, maybe, I don't know. This is my first time trying to work with XML. I also just tested another piece of similar code as given here: https://code.tutsplus.com/parse-xml-to-an-array-in-php-with-simplexml--cms-35529t – but I get to the same dead end.

Comment: The problem is twofold actually: if there is a tag at the beginning of a segment, I can't get to the segment text (even if I manually specify the tag type, e.g. `$TU['tuv'][0]['seg']['bpt']['@attributes'])`. And then, if there are tags inside the segment text, they are skipped altogether, whereas I need to visualise them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to come from `objectsIntoArray()`, and not having the code makes it difficult to fix.

If you remove that call and instead use the SimpleXML elements as they are intended to be used you can call it using (other code removed to focus on this issue)...

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_file($uploadedFile);

foreach($xmlObj->body->tu as $TU) {
    if(isset($TU->tuv[0]->seg)) {
        echo $TU->tuv[0]->seg->asXML();
    }
}
```

Using the `asXML` method will reproduce the content as it was originally, expanding all of the sub elements back into the value.  This will give

```
<seg>
                    <bpt x="1" i="1" type="italic"/>
Формантът -лар/-лар- (от тюрк. -lar) е слабо представен в българската словообразувателна система.<ept i="1"/>
                </seg>

<seg>ПАРТНЬОРИ</seg>
```

you may need to do some more work to produce the result your after, but hopefully this shows how to get there.

Comment: Thanks! This does help. One problem is that it actually prints the `<seg> ... </seg>` tags (visible when you check the TML source)). How do I skip them? And the second proble is that the tags (in this case `<bpt...>` are hidden in the HTML – I will need to print them somehow.